# iOS message forwarding - negotiate a CLASS method and forward

Tags: ios, objective-c, message-forwarding

I'm wondering if it is possible to forward a class method to a different instance. I've had a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) and all the methods shown there are instance level methods. So is there a way I can negotiate and forward a class or static method?

Just for some more Information, the Vision I have is to instead of doing `[ASingleton sharedInstance] somemethod]` I wish to call `someMethod` on `ASingleton` directly.

Comment: @cream-com, I think that method swizzle - is your solution. for a first glance

Comment: [see here](http://cocoadev.com/MethodSwizzling)

Comment: @gaussblurinc if only that blog post had some syntax highlighting and some structure it would be much easier to read! but thanks for the article!

Comment: @cream-com, sorry, but google place it on first position :)

Comment: @gaussblurinc I'm sorry but I think this won't help me? if you look at the code example `orig_method = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, orig_sel);
 alt_method = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, alt_sel);` they both use `getInstanceMethod` :(

Comment: @cream-corn you can use `class_getClassMethod(Class cls, SEL name)`,see `runtime.h`

Comment: Have a look at this http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Comment: Method Swizzling is different for message forwarding, Im not interested in changing the implementation of a (class) method, i want to negotiate/forward a message sent to a class (not instance) and forward that message to an Instance.